# How to redirect 'wget' output stream to 'sftp put'?

Tags: linux, wget, sftp

I tried to take the output stream of wget and pipe it to sftp put, (wget|sftp), but that did not work, How can we do it ?, condition is

> I don't want to save the stream locally in my server as a file.

Is that really possible .?
We can do this with wget | ssh,. I have below command to do sftp and put in single command.

```
sftp user@serverName:/tmp <<< $'put ./fileName'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: TL;DR You can't do it with openssh's `sftp` client, but you can with curl's sftp implementation as demonstrated in this answer, found by Aditya Shaw:

https://serverfault.com/questions/400203/how-to-pipe-data-to-sftp-connection/934153#934153

Basically,

```
$ wget -O - google.com | curl -T - -u remote_user sftp://remote_server/home/remote_user/fileName
```

ENDEDIT

Doesn't seem possible. I tried with:

```
$ wget -O - google.com | sftp -b <(printf "%s\n" 'put /dev/stdin ./fileName') localhost
```

but it seems `sftp` can't copy from non-regular files (like pipes):

```
sftp> put /dev/stdin ./fileName
/dev/stdin is not a regular file
```

Closest thing you can do is probably:

```
$ sftp -b <(printf "%s\n" 'put /dev/stdin ./fileName') localhost < =(wget -O - google.com)
```

This uses zsh's `=()` process substition, which does technically save the contents as a file in `/tmp`, so it fails your condition. zsh automatically deletes it when the command finishes, though.

Comment: so, no solution.

Comment: @VikramSingh If neither `curl` nor `=()` work for your use case, then no.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` has command-line arguments for it.

So, this

```
wget -O - yourlink
```

will sent wget output to `stdout`. Now, you can redirect it wherever you like.

Here `-O -` sends the downloaded file to `stdout`.

[Link to wget Doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Option-Syntax)

Comment: I don't think the problem lies with `wget` as much as it lies with getting `sftp` to upload stdin as a file without having to save the contents to a regular file first. OP says they've done it with `ssh` so that indicates they're already aware of `wget -O -`.

Comment: @JoL Thanks, I misinterpreted the question. I don't have much knowledge about `sftp`. Can you check out [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/934153/580397) and _update_ your answer if it works?